# Where do I mine salt?

Tags: tropico-4

I just told CEO Keith Preston that I would export salt to him.  One problem though, there don't seem to be any salt deposits.  Iron, Bauxite, Gold, but no salt.  Do I just mine salt anywhere?

Comment: Keep in mind that salt mines are a different building from regular mines.  So you won't see the salt deposits until you choose to build the salt mine building.  If you're on the second campaign scenario, there should be plenty of salt deposits.

Comment: @bwarner ...oh wow. Now I feel incredibly stupid. Well as long as the question's here we may as well leave it for future stupid people.  :P I guess you should post that as an answer?

Comment: yx basically had it in his answer, I edited in the clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are salt deposits, you can only place salt mines on salt deposits.  When you choose to build a salt mine (note that they are a different building from normal mines), the map will highlight the potential locations.  If you do not have any, then you cannot complete the quest.  See the picture for an example.

[image]

Comment: I'm fairly sure you're never asked to export a good you *can't* produce on the island, although they will cheerfully ask for cigars even when there's nowhere to plant decent tobacco -- imports count.